# Kernel density estimation in C++

Tags: c++, statistics, computer-vision, kernel-density

I am trying to use Kernel Density Estimation (KDE) to compute the pdf of sample data points of d-dimension. I have read the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_kernel_density_estimation) in which they cite library [libAGF](http://libagf.sourceforge.net/). However this site has no examples nor tutorials. I am reluctant to write the code myself as I'm sure a library would be more optimised (possibly using nearest neighbour search to speed up evaluation).

Does anyone know of any library which implements this functionality?

Comment: have you looked at the [libAGF's Quickstart file](http://libagf.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/libagf/agf/QUICKSTART?revision=1.3&view=markup) ?

Comment: Why was this marked off topic?  Anyway, when I needed it I just wrote it myself, complete with skipping the calculation for more distant neighbors.  I could post the code, but....

Comment: @Michael They close certain topics when posted for C++ that they don't close when posted for other languages. They have pretty horrible reasoning for it, which you can reference in my attempts at C++ encryption questions. Anyhow, if I get you contact information, could you send me your code?

Comment: I have excel formulas... does that help?

Comment: @Michael Yes. I've started a chat for the topic [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107975/kde-estimation-chat).